# How to access popup login form with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying for a while to figure out how to enter username and password in the popup-window in this exercise:

http://pentesteracademylab.appspot.com//lab/webapp/digest

but I am entirely new to Selenium in Python. I found out how to click the button, so that the login form pops up:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://pentesteracademylab.appspot.com//lab/webapp/digest")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
```

but I cannot figure out how to access that window, let alone the fields in it. I have read about `switch_to_frame` and `switch_to_window`. For windows there is the `window_handles` showing you active windows to switch to, but this only returns a single element, which I believe is the main window, not the pop up. I also tried

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
```

to no avail. The problem is that I do not know either which kind of object the popup is (frame,window,alert or something else), and I cannot find any names referring to it in the HTML code for the webpage.

Can anyone take me a step further?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the authentication step by accessing the following URL:

```
http://username:password@pentesteracademylab.appspot.com/lab/webapp/digest/1
```

See also:

- [Handling browser level authentication using Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2755/handling-browser-level-authentication-using-selenium)

Comment: Ah, OK! Thank you! That changes the whole approach entirely. Does that mean that I cannot access the popup? Is the popup somehow not visible to Selenium by any standard approaches?

Comment: @String yeah, this kind of popup cannot be accessed via `selenium`. The provided solution helps to avoid the popup being shown in the first place.

Comment: Great! Yes, I inferred that from the URL :)

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work on Chrome/Windows? The same url works on OSX.

Comment: @gplayer interesting, not sure, could you please elaborate it into a separate question including all the necessary details? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this send very confidential information like username/password in clear-text - which would be a huge security risk ?

Comment: it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

With Selenium version 4.0+ there is a new and more secure way to handle basic authentication. I'm using chrome so I will explain my solution using chrome driver, there should be similar way using another browser

```
Username = input("Your username: ")
Password = input("Your password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})

credentials = base64.b64encode(f"{Username}:{Password}".encode()).decode()
headers = {"headers": {"authorization": "Basic " + credentials}}

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", headers)
driver.get("http://pentesteracademylab.appspot.com//lab/webapp/digest")
```

The accepted solution above is working until now. But there is a security concern/issue because the webserver will log everything without encoding the user and password. Therefore, if the webserver is compromised and the hacker will most likely see the log, then boom they know your username and password.

Please see the official documentation for alternative method and different language:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/cdp_endpoint/#basic-authentication